Help understanding a section of "Why" from Crisis Core
I'm translating the song "Why" from Crisis Core: Final Fantasy VII. The section below is giving me a hard time for several reasons.

視線をそらす　あなたの瞳に
一人で寂しい夜に抱きしめられる
そんな温かさ知ってる？


Is this a long relative clause or not? Is the third line its own phrase?
Does the spacing on the first line signify a break between sentences (there's a pause in the song here)?
Does the passive/potential verb 抱きしめられる apply to あなたの瞳 or 一人で寂しい夜?
Is the first line supposed to be read as あなたの瞳に視線をそらす or as is?


I assume this is the original formatting (I'll add numbers):

(1) 遠い昔に何があったの？
(2A) 視線をそらす　(2B) あなたの瞳に
(3) 一人で寂しい夜に抱きしめられる
(4) そんな温かさ知ってる？

3 and 4 are independent sentences grammatically. そんな in the second sentence connects the two semantically, like "[sentence] - do you know how that feels?" in English. If there was no そんな, the Lines 3-4 would form a sentence where Line 3 modifies 温かさ, though.
2B seems tricky. If we see 2A and 2B as a sentence, it doesn't make much sense semantically - is someone looking away from someone else, or looking into their eyes? It can make more sense if there is something else to look at other than "you", and the speaker is looking away from it and looking into "your" eyes instead. This interpretation took some inference, and is not something I can think of straight away after reading it, though.
If we see 2B and 3 as a sentence, I guess that's technically possible, but the format (a blank line in between) seems to say otherwise, and 2B is a bit too far away from the main verb 抱きしめる, especially with another -に noun in between.
A third possibility is that 2B is a phrase disconnected from phrases before and after. In other words, 2B would form a sentence of its own but as it stands it lacks a verb. That will make the meaning fairly vague and ambiguous.

What about the possibility of 2A and 2B going together like (2B) (2A) あなたの瞳に視線をそらす, where it could translate as "I look away from your eyes."?

That's what I tried to describe in the part starting with "If we see 2A and 2B as a sentence". My interpretation would be "I look away [from somewhere else] to your eyes", though.
